# How to run mc, htop on linux(virtual server) without compiling?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-server

I am using a **virtual shared server** and I would like to have on it some programms like Midnight Commander (mc) or Htop.

The host provider doesn't provide these programs and I don't have access to any package manager or compiler.

I have ssh access to the system and I was wondering if there is a way to just copy and execute these programs without installing or compiling them.

Are there some pre-compiled versions?

PS: If you have a better sugestion for the question/title, please let me know.

Comment: install them using package manager

Comment: I can't. It's a virtual shared server, I don't have access to the package manager.

Comment: You know you can use terminal ls or watch -n 0.5 -x ps -aux | grep myprocess

Answer (score 0):

You said you can't run a package manager. So the only solution I think is:

1- Upload the program, like mc to your home directory.

2- Change the permission to 774. it make mc executable

3- Open an ssh to the server and try to run it.

Maybe, if there are all the files needed installed, MC run.

But another solution if using FTP link.
You can RUN MC in you PC and LINK to the server by FTP.

FTP Link
By default, MC will show you 2 column interfaces. Left and right. Those columns are not only for local directory. You can make one of them or both connected to remote computer using FTP link.

In this case, MC will act as a FTP Client. To connect it into FTP service, you need to press “F9” > FTP Link. MC will ask credential of the FTP. 
http://www.tecmint.com/midnight-commander-a-console-based-file-manager-for-linux/

Comment: Any idea from where can I download a pre-compiled version of the MC for red-hat?

Comment: Why not try first to make an FTP link with “F9” > FTP Link.?

Comment: Better copy MC file from other redhat (or CentOS that is almost equal to Red-Hat).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have access to a package manager, but are you sure you don't have a compiler?

You can get the MC source in a tar file from [here](http://ftp.midnight-commander.org/mc-4.8.17.tar.bz2).

Save it in your "local" or "src" directory and unpack with:

```
tar -xvjf mc-4.8.17.tar.bz2
```

cd into the new directory "mc-4.8.17" and compile with:

```
./configure --prefix=PATH
```

where "PATH" is the full path to your "local" directory.
Then run:

```
make
make install
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install them with your package manager.

On a redhat based distribution (using rpm) :

```
yum install htop mc
```

On a debian based distribution (using deb) :

```
apt-get install htop mc
```

On others, tell me your distribution (arch linux, gentoo, slackware...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's a virtual shared server, it is red-hat based,  I don't have access to yum. I've added these details in the question, so that it's more clear.

Comment: Hi.

Sorry, but if you can't access to a package manager, i'm not sure you can install these tools, even with compiling.

Maybe the best way is to ask to your provider if he can install these packages, or let you to use yum...

Comment: As part of the question: "I don't have access to any package manager", so your answer won't work

Answer (score -1):

htop install in CentOS

yum -y install epel-release

yum update

yum install htop

Comment: As part of the question: "I don't have access to any package manager", so your answer won't work